# Is this topology on the space of locally bounded functions metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let

- $(M,d)$ be a metric $\mathbb R$-vector space
- $\overline B_\varepsilon(x)$ denote the closed ball with radius $\varepsilon>0$ around $x\in M$
- $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space

Now, let $$\left\|f\right\|_{B(K,\:E)}:=\sup_{x\in K}\left\|f(x)\right\|_E\;\;\;\text{for }f:M\to E$$ for $K\subseteq M$ and $$B_{\text{loc}}(M,E):=\left\{f:M\to E\mid\left\|f\right\|_{B(K,\:E)}<\infty\text{ for all compact }K\subseteq M\right\}.$$

Let $\tau$ denote the topology on $B_{\text{loc}}(M,E)$ induced by $\left\{\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{B(K,\:E)}:K\subseteq M\text{ is compact}\right\}$.

> **Question 1**: Is $\tau$ equal to the topology induced by $\left\{\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{B(\overline B_n(0),\:E)}:n\in\mathbb N\right\}$?
>
> **Question 2**: If the answer to question 1 is yes, are we able to conclude that $\tau$ is metrizable via $$d(f,g):=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac1{2^n}\left\|f-g\right\|_{B(\overline B_n(0),\:E)}\;\;\;\text{for }f,g\in B_{\text{loc}}(M,E)?$$

Comment: Some assumptions on the metric space are needed. For example, if $M$ is the real line with the discrete metric and $E$ is the real line then the space is not metrizable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Feel free to add necessary assumptions. However, can I conclude from your comment that your answer to question 1 is *no*?

Comment: That sum need not converge. In general if $(\rho_n)$ is a countable family of seminorms the induced topology is the same as that induced by the metriic $\sum 2^{-n}\rho_n(x-y)/(1+\rho_n(x-y))$.